# Max attribute is not working properly for input type date

Tags: lightning-web-components, date

Hi Currently I am facing issues in the "Max" attribute in `lightning-input` but `max` attribute is not working properly in some cases.

**My requirement is to disable dates after One year of the Current date.**

I got Full date in 11 months but I want the full date in 12 months so that I can give to the max attribute

Below is the attached Screenshot -

[image]

Here is the [Playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/o3_Lrf0N/1/edit) for your reference

Here is the code below

HTML :-

```
<template>

 <lightning-input label="From Date" type="date" name="fromDate"
                                    value={fromDateValue}
                                    message-when-bad-input="Entered Date value is not a valid Date"
                                    onchange={fromdatevalueonchange} placeholder="dd MMM, yyyy" max={fulldate}
                                    message-when-range-overflow="Entered Date value is not a valid Date" required>
                                </lightning-input>     
</template>
```

And JS Code :-

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class LightningExampleInputDate extends LightningElement {
connectedCallback(){
     var x = 12; //or whatever offset
        this.CurrentDate = new Date();
       console.log("Current date:", this.CurrentDate);
       this.CurrentDate.setMonth(this.CurrentDate.getMonth() + x);
       console.log("Date after " + x + " months:", this.CurrentDate);
       this.fulldate = this.CurrentDate.getFullYear() +'-'+this.CurrentDate.getMonth()+'-'+this.CurrentDate.getDate();

       console.log("full date --"+this.fulldate);
}
}
```

Comment: Do you want it to be a fiscal year or the calendar year?

Comment: @rahul calendar year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here `this.CurrentDate.getMonth()`.

The month starts with 0 and not 1.

```
0 -> Jan
1 -> Feb
.
.
10 -> Nov
11 -> Dec
```

Src: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp

Thus to fix your code, you have to add 1 in your month when you create full date.

```
this.fulldate = this.CurrentDate.getFullYear() +'-'+(this.CurrentDate.getMonth()+1)+'-'+this.CurrentDate.getDate();
```

Playground Link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/o3_Lrf0N/4/edit

Comment: Thank you so much mate. It works :)